Question on the parametric variant of the minimum spanning tree problem

Let $G = (V,E, w(t))$ be a connected undirected graph with edge weights defined by $w_e(t) := u_e + t \cdot a_e$, where $a_e, u_e \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $e \in E$. We denote by $T^t$ a minimum spanning tree (MST) in $G$ for a given fixed $t$.
Is the following statement true or false?
There exists a constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T^t$ is a MST in $G$ for all $t \ge k$ and $T^{-t}$  is a maximum spanning tree for all for all $t \le -k$.

I believe that the claim is false, but I do not see how to prove it. Could you please give me a hint?

Taking the first part of the statement to mean that eventually the MSTs stabilize (that is, $T^t = T^k$ for all $t\ge k$), it is true.
The idea (since you are asking for a hint):

The MST only depends on the relative order of the edge weights;
For each pair of edges, the comparison eventually stabilizes, and so the overall ordering of the edges eventually stabilizes.

Taking the second part of the statement to mean that for all $t \ge k$, $T^{-t}$ is a maximum spanning tree with respect to weights $w(t)$, it is mostly true.
Specifically, it it is true provided that all the $a_e$ are distinct. To see quickly why this hypothesis is necessary, consider the extreme opposite case, where $a_e = 0$ for all $e$: now $T^t = T^0$ for all $t$, positive and negative, and so it is always a MinST and not a MaxST.
The idea from here is to look at two edges $e,f$ and show that for large enough $t$, if $a_e \ne a_f$, then the comparison between $w_e(t)$ and $w_f(t)$ goes the opposite way from the comparison between $w_e(-t)$ and $w_f(-t)$. Then, extrapolate to what this means for the global ordering.
